# How to get the base or root url in sailsjs?

Tags: node.js, url, express, root, sails.js

Is there a sails way of extracting the root or base url of an app? I basically need this for sending activation emails with links.

Comment: Wish I could answer your question, but thanks for the inadvertent pointer to sails! Looks really slick. That said, have you tried asking in their IRC channel? irc://irc.freenode.net/sailsjs

Comment: I got my answer here but thanks for the heads up about irc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sails.js is based on Express, so from within your action you can do the following:

```
var protocol = req.connection.encrypted?'https':'http';
var baseUrl = protocol + '://' + req.headers.host + '/';
```

Comment: You're missing a + before req.headers.host. It works perfectly thanks.

Comment: @bredikhin I send an email to confirm account when registering users, so I want to check if the link is correctly written. How ca I know where the request of the link is coming from?

Answer (score 3):

Just to give an updated answer for anyone that finds this page...

In Sails v0.10 you can access it through `req.baseUrl` or `sails.getBaseurl()` in your views.

Answer taken from: [How to get current domain address in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625935/how-to-get-current-domain-address-in-sails-js)

Comment: sails.getBaseurl() is deprecated :(

Answer (score 0):

A couple other options available... `sails.config.appPath` or `require('path').resolve('.')` and both will return a path from your app's drive to the app root. Caveat is local development as `C:\websites\mywebsite\remote` is not very useful and any loaded asset will be blocked by the browser.

This [source](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/file-uploads) uses the require.resolve() function to calculate the absolute path of `appPath` and appending `assets/images`.

```
req.file('avatar').upload({
  dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images')
},function (err, uploadedFiles) {
  if (err) return res.negotiate(err);

  return res.json({
    message: uploadedFiles.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!'
  });
});
```

In the above example you could change `'assets/images'` to `'../assets/images'` to store file uploads below the root of your website - if you are into hiding your stuff!

Here is a [good article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3243-using-require-resolve-to-calculate-module-relative-file-paths-in-node-js.htm) about `require.resolve()`.