# How to get current domain address in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I trying to get current web address using [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org).

I tried the following:

```
req.param('host') and req.param('X-Forwarded-Protocol')
```

**returns undefined.**

```
req.headers.host
```

**returns localhost.** but my domain is not localhost.

How to get it ??

Answer (score 8):

> Just to preface this answer: there is no reliable, cross-platform way to automatically detect the external URL of a running Sails app (or any other Node app).  The `getBaseUrl()` method described below uses a combination of *user-supplied* and default configuration values to make a best guess at an app's URL.  In mission-critical situations, you are advised to pre-determine the URL and save it in a custom [environment-dependent configuration value](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/configuration#?environmentspecific-files-config-env) (e.g. `sails.config.appUrl`) that you can reference elsewhere in the app.

If you're on Sails >= v0.10.x, you can use `sails.getBaseurl()` to get the full protocol, domain and port that your app is being served from.  Starting with Sails v0.10.0-rc6, this also checks the `sails.config.proxyHost` and `sails.config.proxyPort`, which you can set manually in your one of your config files (like `config/local.js`) if your app is being served via a proxy (e.g. if it's deployed on Modulus.io, or proxied through an Nginx server).

Sails v0.9.x doesn't have `sails.getBaseurl`, but you can always try copying the code and implementing yourself, probably in a [service](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/services.md):

**getBaseUrl**

```
function getBaseurl() {
  var usingSSL = sails.config.ssl && sails.config.ssl.key && sails.config.ssl.cert;
  var port = sails.config.proxyPort || sails.config.port;
  var localAppURL =
    (usingSSL ? 'https' : 'http') + '://' +
    (sails.getHost() || 'localhost') +
    (port == 80 || port == 443 ? '' : ':' + port);

  return localAppURL;
};
```

you'll notice this relies on `sails.getHost()`, which looks like:

```
function getHost() {
  var hasExplicitHost = sails.config.hooks.http && sails.config.explicitHost;
  var host = sails.config.proxyHost || hasExplicitHost || sails.config.host;
  return host;
};
```

Comment: it returns localhost.. Is there a way we get the IP address of the lifted application??

Answer (score 7):

In Sails v0.10 you can access it through `req.baseUrl` or `sails.getBaseurl()` in your views..

Comment: This worked for me and seems the easiest & quicker way than rest of the answers

Answer (score 1):

I have tried some examples I have found in google but nothing seemed to work at least in my local machine.

1. Using this in my local machine returned:

   ```
   req.ip;  -->  ::1
   ```
2. Using this in my local machine returned:

   ```
   req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];  -->  undefined
   ```
3. Finally, using this in my local machine returned:

   ```
   var paramIp = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
               req.connection.remoteAddress ||
               req.socket.remoteAddress ||
               req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;  -->  ::1
   ```

Nothing seemed to work. Then I tried in ***`production environment`*** and the first example returned:

```
req.ip;  -->  ::ffff:10.155.43.243
```

It seems to be working but as you can see it is an IPv6 ip address so that's not what I wanted.

And the example number 3 returned:

```
187.214.247.196
```

So that's excellent because that's what I needed.

All I have to said is that the example number 3 worked fine but just in production environment (**using [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com)**) not for development in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

**req.host** should contain the host value.

Comment: There is no host object under req , its retuns undefined.

Comment: You mean req.headers.host. but this returns always localhost :(

Comment: I just tested this to make sure, and it works fine for me on sails 0.9.x

Comment: Looking through the 0.10 code it seems that this shold work for sure. You could also inspect **sails.config.host** which should hold the *configured* hostname. If you don't access the node.js process directly then for example nginx could convolute this and thus mess up the detection in sails.js

Answer (score 0):

On sails 0.10.x, you could do this:

```
//inside controller action
var baseURL = req.protocol + '://' + req.host;
```

`req.protocol` will give you 'http' or 'https' (or whatever application protocol). `req.host` will be the host's header, e.g. 'sub.domain.com'

As noted in a comment above, `sails.getBaseURL()` or any of it's variants will usually return localhost, even in a production environment.

Comment: How can I implement that in an service module stored in /api/services/someservice.js that has no "req" param? Because it is not associated to a url request.

Comment: It depends how you build the service. 

In some cases, I simply pass `baseURL` as a parameter into he service (assuming it's called from a controller).

In other cases, I'll do something silly in the service like this:

`var baseUrl = (process.env.NODE_ENV=='development') ? 'http://localhost:133/' : 'https://myappexamplesite.com'`

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for getting the IP of any server based on Node.js and it works with Sails.js:

```
var os = require('os');
....
  getIpAddress: function() {
    var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    for (k in ifaces) {
      for (k2 in ifaces[k]) {
        var address = ifaces[k][k2];
        if (address.family == 'IPv4' && !address.internal) {
          return(address.address);
        }
      }
    }
    return(null);
  }
...
```