# Sails.js + passport behind Nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, sails.js, passport.js, passport-twitter

I've started a new Sails.js project and want to implement passport-twitter for authentication.

Everything is implemented correctly using the sails-generator-auth module, but after Twitter authorization I get redirected to

```
http://localhost:9090/auth/twitter/callback
```

Sails is running behind nginx on localhost:9090 - how can I override the hostname?

So far I tried setting app.set('trust proxy'); in config/env/development.js

```
   http: {
    customMiddleware: function(app) {
      console.log('trust proxy');
      app.enable('trust proxy');
    }
  },
```

I see the console.log output when I lift sails, but it doesn't affect the redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple, but not very well documented. There's another post which actually talks about a slighty different problem, but leads to the correct answer:
[How to get current domain address in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625935/how-to-get-current-domain-address-in-sailsjs)

> If you're on Sails v0.10.x, you can use sails.getBaseurl() to get the full protocol, domain and port that your app is being served from. Starting with Sails v0.10.0-rc6, this also checks the sails.config.proxyHost and sails.config.proxyPort, which you can set manually in your one of your config files (like config/local.js) if your app is being served via a proxy (e.g. if it's deployed on Modulus.io, or proxied through an Nginx server).

It is correct to configure a sails instance to localhost:9090, but if you want to change the hostname/port behind a proxy, you have to configure `proxyHost`and `proxyPort` - this can be done anywhere, but is most suitable in `local.js`

Comment: /* example local.js */
module.exports = {
    proxyHost: 'some.domain'
};